# VB.NET Using regex to remove spaces from a string

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, space

I used

```
Dim regSpace As New Regex(" ")
```

as Regular Expression.

And then the code to write a line on a file:

```
If msktxt_InsOrientationV.Text <> "" Then
    txtfile.WriteLine(regSpace.Replace(msktxt_InsOrientationV.Text, String.Empty))
Else
    Error_Handler("Error") 'generates a message box
End If
```

The string in msktxt_InsOrientationV.Text is "40 °/120°/240°/300°" (without quotes). I want to remove the space, so it should be: "40°/120°/240°/300°" but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? P.S. I'm using masked textboxes.

Comment: In these cases, there are non-breaking spaces, try with `Dim regSpace As New Regex("\s+")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for the reply, I tried your solution but the space remains

Comment: @Sharix What is the value of `AscW(msktxt_InsOrientationV.Text(2))`? (Trying to find out exactly what character it is.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's 32

Comment: @Sharix 32 represents an ordinary space character, so it looks like something is going wrong somewhere else than in the code shown.

Comment: @AndrewMorton but I cannot find where. It should write the line in the text file without any space (because of regular expression) but it continues to write the "before-regex" text. I've tried to use some string variables filled with the original text and then applied regex on those, but it didn't work anyway.

Comment: @Sharix Are you *sure* you're checking the correct file? If the full path to the file wasn't specified when opening `txtfile`, it might not be where you intended it to be.

Comment: can you just use `txtfile.WriteLine(msktxt_InsOrientationV.Text.Replace(" ". ""))` instead of regex?

Comment: Code works for me.

Comment: Ah, regular expressions. The source of eons of wailing and gnashing of teeth. If you have no compelling reason to use them, and a simpler alternative exists (i.e., `String.Replace`) flee them as you would a hoard of cannibals armed with chainsaws and barbecue sauce.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, the file is the right one, and if exists it will be overwritten.

Comment: @Sharix If you put a breakpoint at the line that writes to the file and run the project in debug mode, does it get to that line? Also, it might be best to delete the file manually before running it, just to make sure.